# JavaFX Overlapping Scenes

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I'm creating a game that I would like to consist of 2 scenes.  One scene holds all the game pieces and one scene overlays the first to display hud items.

Is this a poor way to make my HUD overlay?
Can I simply add the Pane of my hud to the first scene and only use one?

Any suggestions would be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add the Pane to the Group that is the root of my one and only scene using this code:
`initGroup.getChildren().addAll(fieldBg, hud.getUiPane());`

However, I do receive a NullPointerException when trying to instantiate the object that creates the Pane; I have a feeling it's unrelated to this issue though.

Comment: Group is good for fixed size controls.  If your layout contains resizable nodes thence requires CSS styling then [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) is good.